# Postgres: Dump schema-only but leave data intact for a few tables

Tags: database, postgresql, pg-dump

I have a database with ~300 tables which I'd like to dump schema-only. The caveat is there are about 12 tables which I'd like to keep the data as well. e.g. I have a table called country which has names of countries in it which I'd like saved in the dump.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dump the schema first:

```
pg_dump -s -d dbname > /home/username/schema.sql
```

Dump the tables you want data from next:

```
pg_dump -a -d dbname -t table1name -t table2name -t table3name > /home/username/data.sql
```

And then to restore on a new server, run the files in the same order (schema first).

```
psql -U user -d dbname -f /home/username/schema.sql
psql -U user -d dbname -f /home/username/data.sql
```

If you want, you can also append the second dump (data) onto the first (schema) to create one big file to restore by using >> instead of >.  You're still running two pg_dump commands to do so, though.

For example:

```
pg_dump -s -d dbname > /home/username/full.sql
pg_dump -a -d dbname -t table1name -t table2name -t table3name >> /home/username/full.sql
psql -U dbuser -d dbname -f /home/username/full.sql
```

Comment: Does this create two dump files?

Comment: It will.  I updated the answer with an example of saving it to file.